# Modelling friendship with aws amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

Here is an example of my schema

```
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  friends: [Friendship] @connect(name: "UserFriends")
  outgoingFriendRequests: [FriendRequest] @connect(name: "SenderRequests")
  incomingFriendRequests: [FriendRequest] @connect(name: "ReceiverRequests")
}

type Friendship @model {
  id: ID!
  user: User! @connect(name: "UserFriends")
  friend: User! @connect

type FriendRequest @model {
  id: ID!
  sender: User! @connect(name: "SenderRequests")
  receiver: User! @connect(name: "ReceiverRequests")
```

Here assume for `userA` and `userB`,
suppose `userA` added `userB` as friend(added an entry to friendship model).

```
{
  id: 'some-id
  user: user-A-id
  friend: user-B-id

}
```

Here we can query the `userA`'s `friends` field to see `userB` as his friend(by relationship below)

```
@connect(name: "UserFriends")
```

But for `userB`, `userA` is still not available in its `friends` field. Is there any workaround we can do in the model design in order to mutually notify the added friendship. Or am I doing something wrong?